# Sitecore FXM Add External Website from Internal Staging Server

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-fxm

I am trying to add an external website to my Sitecore FXM, however our staging(CM) server is inside an internal firewall and we have no intention to expose it to the public. And the auto generated beacon script uses our staging domain, thus it can't work out in the public.

My questions are:

1. Can I just change the domain in the script to use my public domain?
2. What is the recommended way to set this up in a staging(CM/CD) environment?

Reference: [Sitecore Doc: Add External Website in FXM](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/digital_marketing/federated_experience_manager/using_fxm/add_an_external_website_in_fxm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use your public domain.  The beacon script should be on the delivery server.  There is a setting named `FXM.Hostname` that you can change to make it generate the correct tag.  Instructions on configuring for a scaled environment are available here: [Configuring FXM](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/digital_marketing/federated_experience_manager/configuring/configuring_fxm)

Comment: Thank you very much, that link you shared helps a lot!